# do jupyter magic-commands work on vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to use the javascript magic commands in a jupyter notebook to modify some html on vscode, but it didn't work. is there a way to make it work?
Here is what im trying to do.

```
%%html
<div id="test">Hello</div>
```

```
%%javascript
document.getElementById("test") = "Hello js"
```

Images of the notebooks.

[vscode-jupyte-notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DY9E.png)

[jupyter-notbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPXYq.png)

Comment: You can't assign to a call. In the second screenshot, you're assigning to a properly, `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, same as Google Colab, VSCode accepts Jupyter [cell magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html). Launching and modifying Jupyter notebooks within the code editor using  [VSCode's Jupyter plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter).

Here is an example from my recent assignment code, I've commanded `%%writefile` on the top of the cell.

```py
%%writefile assignments/kerateclub.py

import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def average_degree(num_edges, num_nodes):
  avg_degree=np.round((num_edges*2)/num_nodes)
  return avg_degree

def average_clustering_coefficient(G):
  avg_cluster_coef=np.round(nx.average_clustering(G), 2)
  return avg_cluster_coef


G=nx.karate_club_graph()
num_edges=G.number_of_edges()
num_nodes=G.number_of_nodes()
avg_degree=average_degree(num_edges, num_nodes)
print("Average degree of karate club network is {}".format(avg_degree))
avg_cluster_coef=average_clustering_coefficient(G)
print("Average clustering coefficient of karate club network is {}".format(avg_cluster_coef))
```

Eventually, I shall easily get `kerateclub.py` file inside my pre-build `assignments` directory.